# Best Practice for hardware upgrade - reinstall Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, dell

I am preparing for hardware upgrades for PowerEdge 1950 Gen II, PowerEdge 2950 Gen II servers and PowerEdge r710 within our DC. They all run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The upgrades involve upgrades of RAM and replace the CPUs in the following order:

- PE1950 - 8gb ram to 32gb ram, Intel Xeon E5335 to Intel Xeon E5450
- PE2950 - 8gb ram to 32gb ram, Intel Xeon 5160 to Intel Xeon E5450
- PEr710 - 8gb ram to 32gb ram, Intel Xeon E5520 to Intel Xeon L5630

As you can notice the hardware change is substantial and would like to ask if it would be best practice to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 past the upgrades.

I know that Ubuntu would still run, but I have my doubts that the kernel compiled for the old cpus (during the install) would be supporting the new CPUs in full (e.g. microcode, power management, c-states, etc.) For instance the Intel Xeon E5335 had no power management *adversus* the E5450. SWAP is another issue that is being updated to meet the size of the new memory.

Your opinion matters to me.

Comment: Huh? These servers are ancient, and so are the replacement parts you propose to install. Why are you even concerned about reinstalling the OS?

Comment: Did you compile the kernel yourself with some non-default changes?

Comment: If did not compile the kernel yourself - you do not have to reinstall Ubuntu. It is only RAM and CPU upgrade

Comment: @MichaelHampton they are legacy, but still in pristine condition. Being a non-profit we have to make use of what we have to the fullest extent. My reinstall concern is due to the kernel not having the correct or ideal firmware.

Comment: @Orphans no the kernel was complied by the debian installer during the initial install.

Comment: The kernel is not compiled during installation. That happens long before installation on a build server somewhere. Every Ubuntu installation uses the same kernel unless someone explicitly replaces it.

Comment: @Fab If it's a standard Ubuntu installation, just replace your hardware and you're good to go. Changing swap size later is easy.

Comment: @Lenniey was of the idea that the installer compiles the kernel over the existing inventory and falls back to generic for any upgraded parts

Comment: @Fab no, look at Michael Hampton's comment. If your CPU is supported by Ubuntu (which it is, of course), then you'll have absolutely no trouble. Just change the appropriate settings in BIOS (if any) and all is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to reinstall.  You need to rebuild the *initramfs*, though (run "*update-initramfs -u -kall*" as root) *after* you boot with the new processor, to give the *intel-microcode* package a chance to detect and install the required microcode update for your new processor.  Then you need to reboot again to activate any relevant microcode updates.

Please ensure you updated the system firmware (UEFI/BIOS) to the latest available **before** you update the RAM and processor.

Note that depending on the version of Ubuntu, it will ship a known-broken version of *iucode-tool* that cannot automatically handle "mixed stepping" systems (where you have two Xeon processors with different steppings in the same system). In that case, you will have to do some manual configuration in /etc/default/intel-microcode.

Comment: Thanks for the initramfs update. I was thinking that some form of update needs to be done. Will update with the outcome of when the new CPUs arrive. The Ubuntu version is 16.04 could you refer me to some guidance for mixed stepping configs pls.